# Unable to update records - SQL Server 2008 R2 Server/Express and MS Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: frameworks, synchronization

I am using MS Sync Framework 2.1 and syncing multiple SQL Express 2008 R2 express clients with SQL Express 2008 R2 server. It has been working fine for many months until recently. One of the table with 3000 records is not getting synced any more. I populated the table with Bulk Insert. I cannot even update those records through query analyser using SQL Management Studio.

When I run the T-Sql Update query as

```
Update myTable set modifiedDate ='sa'
```

It returns the following message.

```
(0) records updated

(3000) records updated
```

The first message is for myTable and second is for myTable_Tracking. So the records are not getting updated in myTable but they are in myTable_Tracking. But when I do Select query I am getting 3000 rows returned.

The same result is found on both Server and Express.

I checked size of transaction log. The Space Used is 94% on SQL Server 2008 R2 Server but on SQL Express Space Used is 17% only.

Any idea people? 
Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'd assume there was a trigger on the table.

Comment: That;s right. Sync Framework creates about 12 triggers for each table. But the question is why it happens only for one table and 3000 records. Other 120 odd tables are syncing fine except this one.

Comment: And I can still see the updated value in the table column when the records are returned by Select query.

Comment: There should only 3 triggers per table created by sync framework, so you should check what those other triggers are. Also, sync fx does change tracking via triggers, so you should be wary of loading data via statements that don't normally fire triggers by default such as bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend that you take a look on this link:

https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/things-you-need-to-know-about-sql-data-sync-service/